# Drawing a grid for the heat equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to draw a 1-D grid for the heat equation like the image (I just need the grid and what's written above and bellow it, the part on the right is just for clarity)

Given:

- x in [a,b], with a = -b
- t in [0,T]
- h = b-a/n+1, for n+1 given points
- \tau = T/m, for m given points

And a rectangle covering the first row with "known values" below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach using `\foreach` loops:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={font=\strut},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \foreach \x [count=\i from 1] in {1,...,7} {%
            \foreach \y [count=\ii from 1] in {1,...,4} {%
            \draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt] node (circ-\i-\ii) {};
            \draw (1,\y) -- (7,\y);
            \draw (\x,1) -- (\x,4);         
            }
        }
    
        \node[below] at (circ-1-1) {$x_0=a$};
        \node[below] at (circ-7-1) {$x_{n+1}=b$};
        \node[below=10pt, orange] at (circ-4-1) {known values};
        \node[below] at (circ-4-1) {$t=0$};
        \node[above] at (circ-4-4) {$t_m=T$};
        
        \draw[orange, fill=orange, opacity=0.25] (0.875,0.875) rectangle (7.125,1.125);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just this?

[image: grid]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) grid[ystep=0.5] (6,3);
        \draw[orange,rounded corners] (-.25,-.25) rectangle (6.25,0.25) node [midway,below=8pt] {known values};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need more than that. I need also to mark each interesction and write $x_{0} = a$ at the bottom left and $x_{n+1} = b at bottom right. And the same with the t in the places I wrote